# Spring RestTemplate Handling Multiple Responses

Tags: spring, spring-rest

I'm consuming a restful service, What I observed is based on the request I see multiple responses for the same end point.

For Ex : I request a GET call with the some parameters for a PDF document.
if the response is good and the content type is application/pdf its giving a pdf document.

if the document is not available, the content type is application/xml and the response is giving the error code, error description.

Any input is much appreciated !

Thanks,
Sudheer.

Comment: What is your error? or your question ?

Comment: sorry, my question is how to handle multiple responses based on the content type.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ResponseEntity class of Spring, you can set the class to return the object what you want. You can change the content type, and everything you want.

here there is an example of file

```
@RequestMapping(value = URIConstansts.GET_FILE, produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getFile(@RequestParam(value="fileName", required=false) String fileName,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{

    ResponseEntity respEntity = null;

    byte[] reportBytes = null;
    File result=new File("/home/arpit/Documents/PCAP/dummyPath/"+fileName);

    if(result.exists()){
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/arpit/Documents/PCAP/dummyPath/"+fileName);
        String type=result.toURL().openConnection().guessContentTypeFromName(fileName);

        byte[]out=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type",type);

        respEntity = new ResponseEntity(out, responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
    }else{
        respEntity = new ResponseEntity ("File Not Found", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return respEntity;
}
```

Here there is an example of Json

```
@ResponseBody ResponseEntity<? extends AbstractResponse> createUser(@RequestBody String requestBody) {
    if(!valid(requestBody) {
        ErrorResponse errResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        //populate with error information
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> (errResponse, HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    createUser();
    CreateUserSuccessResponse successResponse = new CreateUserSuccessResponse();
    // populate with more info
    return new ResponseEntity<CreateUserSuccessResponse> (successResponse, HTTPSatus.OK);
}
```